# Zedgraph vertical scrollbar for multiple y-axis

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

I have a zedgraph control which consists of up to 6 y-axis. (which is added using YAxisList.Add(axis))

I have added vertical scrollbar by setting IsShowVScrollBar = true.
When I try to scroll the y-axis, only the first axes able to be scrolled, while the other axis remain unscrolled. How can I scroll all the y-axis together using the same scrollbar?

Comment: I did find a "IsSynchronizeYAxes" property - but this does not seem to have any effect either. I eventually resolved the issue using the ScrollEvent & manually adjusting all but the first entry in the YAxisList (YAxis seems to be a reference to YAxisList[0]).

Comment: That means you did it by manually adjusting maximum and minimum of all the axis in ScrollEvent?

Comment: I don't know if the is a "correct" way to do it - I expected the synchronize property to work - but that is exactly what I did.